# Adding line to file in ansible task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ansible, passenger

I need add in ansible task to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf two lines(for deploy):

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;
```

This line I add to end of file("include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;"):

```
- name: Include passenger in nginx.conf
  become: yes
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf regexp="^\s*# include \/etc\/nginx\/passenger.conf;" line="        include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;"
```

But this lines must be in html{...} block, not in the end of file.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's `insertafter` option for `lineinfile` module.

You can do something like this:

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    line: "        include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;"
    insertafter: '^\s*include /etc/nginx/conf-components.d/\*.conf;\s*$'
    # insertafter: '^http {$'
```

To insert your include just after `*.conf` includes, or just after `http {` opening tag.

It is not useful if you have many identical blocks. But for unique markers it's good enough.

Comment: One question - can I check this file and insert my lines, only if this lines not found in file? Because if this strings be duplicated, nginx be crashed.

Comment: This module should be idempotent – it should add the line only if it is not there. So the first run will give you yellow changed state and the second run will give you green state with nothing to be changed.

Comment: Cool! It's really green state at second run. Thanks!